# What environment variables do I need to set for Java?

Tags: java, bash

I don't know Java, but I am calling (from Ubuntu) something that requires it. I've `export`ed `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `JAVA_HOME`. But I don't know what other environment variables Java might need. Without knowing what terms to google, I can't google.

Is there some common list of environment variables that always need to be set for Java, or will they all be specific to my application (rJava)?

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH isn't even related .. in any case, see `man java` (or `man whatever`) which will usually explain the environment variables, if any, used.

Comment: That should be fine, although you may need the `java` binary in your `PATH` depending on how the app is launched. But since you're posting I infer it didn't work - tell us about the error / symptoms?

Comment: @user2864740 Hmm, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was the solution to http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/littler-and-rJava-td4641410.html.

Comment: @dvnrrs Thanks. In my googling to check out this question before I asked it I found a reference to `PATH`. That reference said it `java -version` works then java is in the `PATH`. My `java -version` does run. ||||| As for my problem, it could be totally non-Java related. I'm just trying to cover my Java-related bases so I can be sure it's not that. (given I know nothing about Java it's the hardest error to source, hence my ignorant question)

Comment: @isomorphismes That's to placate the running program, not Java (or the JVM) itself.

Comment: I have worked with commercial java packages that required custom settings for both CLASSPATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: @John1024 Thanks John. Useful info.

Comment: If 3rd party native libraries are used by java directly, then they *should* be declared with a -Djava.library.path switch (unless the related jar adds them under the curtains).  Now, that 3rd party library might need other libraries, and how it finds them depends on how it was built.  Many will require LD_LIBRARY_PATH to be set, but java shouldn't be using that value directly.

Comment: @TedBigham Thanks for this, Ted, and for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java binary doesn't require any variables by default.  It get's it config info from command line switches.  Many scripts generate switches from environment variables before launching java, so those are specific to each script.

Comment: +1. I haven't set environment variables for Java any time in this century.